# Difference between adherent point, boundary point and limit point ?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

What are their differences I cannot distinguish them from their definitions.

Comment: Also is adherent point another name for closure point?

Comment: limit point is also called cluster point or accumulation point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $S$ be a set in some topological space $(X,\tau)$. Denote by $S^\circ,S^-$ the interior and closure of $S$, respectively.

1. If $x \in S^-$, $x$ is an **adherent point** of $S$.
2. If $x \in S^- \setminus S^\circ$, $x$ is an **boundary point** of $S$.
3. If there exists a sequence $(x_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ in $S$ so that $x_j \neq x$ and $x_j \to x$, $x$ is a **limit point** of $S$.

Assuming that the topology on $X$ is induced by a metric $d$, then

1. If $\forall r > 0, B(x;r) \cap S \neq \emptyset$, $x$ is an adherent point.
2. If $\forall r > 0, B(x;r) \cap S \neq \emptyset, B(x;r) \cap S^c \neq \emptyset$, $x$ is a boundary point.
3. If $\forall r > 0, B(x;r) \setminus \{x\} \cap S \neq \emptyset$, $x$ is a limit point.